# How to enable kubernetes commands autocomplete

Tags: kubernetes

I'm tired of writing all `kubectl` and `kubeadm` commands by hand. Is there any way of enabling autocomplete on these commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Bash Solution

```
# Execute these commands
$ echo "source <(kubectl completion bash)" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "source <(kubeadm completion bash)" >> ~/.bashrc

# Reload bash without logging out
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

## kubectl

For Bash autostartup and current session:

```bash
# update settings
cat <<'EOF' >> ~/.bashrc
source <(kubectl completion bash)
alias k=kubectl
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl k
EOF

# reload settings
source ~/.bashrc
```

For current terminal session only:

```bash
source <(kubectl completion bash)
alias k=kubectl
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl k
```

`k` is an alias for `kubectl`. Thus the following commands are the same:

```bash
kubectl get pods
k get pods
```

For other shells, you may enable autocomplete as well. Check the output:

```
$ kubectl completion --help
...
source <(kubectl completion zsh)
kubectl completion fish | source
kubectl completion powershell | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
...
```

There will be instruction for each shell, including autostartup.

## kubeadm

For Bash autostartup and current session:

```bash
# update settings
cat <<'EOF' >> ~/.bashrc
source <(kubeadm completion bash)
alias ka=kubeadm
complete -F __start_kubeadm ka
EOF

# reload settings
source ~/.bashrc
```

For current terminal session only:

```bash
source <(kubeadm completion bash)
alias ka=kubeadm
complete -F __start_kubeadm ka
```

`ka` is an alias for `kubeam`. Thus the following commands are the same:

```bash
kubeadm version
ka version
```

For other shells, you may enable autocomplete as well. Check the output:

```
$ kubeadm completion --help
...
source <(kubeadm completion zsh)
...
```

(for now, there are only bash and zsh are supported)